# Copy the value of a single cell from a data frame onto clipboard in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can't figure out how to copy a specific cell value onto the clipboard so I can paste it.

filtered.to_clipboard(index=False, columns=['ABC'])
That gives me a specific column, but I want a specific row and column. For example:

filtered.to_clipboard(index=False, columns=['ABC'], rows=[1])

But that doesn't work.  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first select the value, indexing with lists, so that a dataframe is returned. Then you can apply the `to_clipboard` method:

```py
df = filtered
col = 'ABC'
row = 1

df.loc[[row], [col]].to_clipboard(index=False, header=False)
```